# Prevent Flask from Displaying '.html' in URL

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I'm working on a project, using Flask. Apart from the index page, all other pages have '.html' extension displayed at the end of their URL (for example `127.0.0.1:5000/mypage.html`), which is normal. For some reasons, i do not want the extension displayed, i prefer the URL displays with the extension (like this `127.0.0.1:5000/mypage`. Here's what i have:

> Flask

```
@app.route('/mypage', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def mypage():
    return render_template('/mypage.html')
```

> HTML

```
<a href="mypage.html">Mypage</a></li>
```

I'll appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Hey Seyi, thanks for the marking the answer. I am glad it worked out for you. I would appreciate your upvote as well :) Indeed some more for the efforts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the documentation: [Creating URLs in Flask](https://overiq.com/flask-101/creating-urls-in-flask/), you can do this like this, and you are pretty much good to go.

**Please Note:** Do not use `/` inside the `render_template`

```
@app.route('/mypage', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():        
    return render_template('mypage.html')
```

If you want to hardcode the url, you can use `url_for()`. But as the documentation says:

> Flask can generate URLs using the `url_for()` function of the flask package. *Hardcoding URLs in the templates and view functions is a bad practice*.

**HTML**

```
<a href="/mypage">Mypage</a></li>
```